# Magento setting up 2 stores on1 domain and 1 sub-domain with 1 install

Tags: magento

I know the Magento community forum would be a better place to post this but every time I post something there, no one answer.

First let me explain my setup. I have 1 install on magento 1.8 on my main site, let’s call it domain1.com. This store is working fine and almost ready to go. Now I need another store on a subdomain, let’s call is store.domain2.com.

I’ve check a lot of forums and tutorial and I still can’t figure out what my problem is. Here’s what I’ve done so far.

Step 1, I create my subdomain store.domain2.com and make it point at my magento folder which is domain1/magento on my server.

Step 2, I create my new root category I called domain2.com

Step 3, I create my new website I called domain2.com too

Step 4, I create my new store I called DOMAIN2 which I made the default store for the website created in step 3. The root category for this store is the one created in step 2.

Step 5, I create a couple of store view for the languages, all are enabled.

Step 6, in System -> Configuration -> Web tab, after selecting my newly created website in the Current Configuration Scope section, I change the secure and unsecure Base URL for https://store.domain2.com and http://store.domain2.com

Step 7, in the .htaccess file located in the domain1/magento folder, I add those lines at the end of the file:
    SetEnvIf Host domain1.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
    SetEnvIf Host domain1.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
    SetEnvIf Host ^domain1.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
    SetEnvIf Host ^domain1.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

```
SetEnvIf Host store\.domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2
SetEnvIf Host store\.domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^store\.domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2
SetEnvIf Host ^store\.domain2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

CODE=base is because I left the default value for my first store
CODE=domain2 is because that is the code name I gave to the domain2.com website (in magento)

Now the problem is when I go to store.domain2.com, the store of domain1.com appear and I can’t figure out how to make my second store appear instead.

Plus, I set the domain2.com as default just to see the result and both my sites are displaying a magento frame with no content, even if I created categories for my second store.

Anyone can help me on this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll be referring to `store.domain2.com` as `sub.domain2.com` to avoid confusing store and subdomain.

If your main store is on `domain1.com` and you need to have `sub.domain2.com` as your second store you need to make sure that you can access Magento core files of your `domain1.com` from `sub.domain2.com` folder. If it's possible then these are my corrections:

**Step 1**, make symlinks in `sub.domain2.com` public folder that point to Magento core files in 'domain1.com' folder. Don't point the whole folder because you need custom `index.php` and `.htaccess`. Go to your public dir of `sub.domain2.com` and type:

```
ln -s /existing/magento/path/public_html/skin /pointing/to/existing/path/public_html/skin
```

exchanging the paths to fit your case. Then do the same for all folders from the core installation.

**Step 6a**, go to System>Configuration>General>Web>Url Options and set 'Auto-redirect to Base URL' to 'No'.

**Step 7**, remove. Copy `index.php` and `.htaccess` to your `sub.domain2.com` folder - the one with symlinks created in Step 1. Now modify these files

- .htaccess, at the end of the file add:

  ```
  SetEnvIf Host www.sub.domain2.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2
  SetEnvIf Host www.sub.domain2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
  SetEnvIf Host ^sub.domain2.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2
  SetEnvIf Host ^sub.domain2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
  ```

  where `domain2` is a name of a new view under the `sub.domain2.com`.
  These variables will be later used in `index.php` file.

---

sidenote:
if you'd like to set up your store in subfolder you need to use this `.htaccess` code instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/fr/$
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:domain2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:%1]
```

or simply set these up in `index.php`

---

- index.php (optional)

  If something doesn't work after modifying `.htaccess` modify last 3 lines of code in the `index.php` directly:

  ```
  /* Store or website code */
  // $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
  $mageRunCode = 'domain2';

  /* Run store or run website */
  // $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
  $mageRunType = 'store';

  Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
  ```

  If you had any issues with symlinks modify `MAGE_ROOT` constant on the top of this file. If not you should be done.